# Reusable string in angular app

Tags: angularjs

In a application, some objects have icons. In PHP I would call

```
class Icons {
    const OBJECT_A_ICON = 'fa-icona';
    const OBJECT_B_ICON = 'fa-iconb';
    const OBJECT_C_ICON = 'fa-iconc';
}

echo Icons::OBJECT_C_ICON;
```

What is the best approach to do this in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `constant` service.

**[Constant Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant)**.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .constant('ICON_CONSTANT', {
    Icon_A: 'fa-icona',
    Icon_B: 'fb-iconb',
    Icon_C: 'fc-iconc'
  })
  .controller('cntrl', function($scope, ICON_CONSTANT) {
      $scope.icon = ICON_CONSTANT.Icon_A;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="cntrl">
    {{ icon }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

angular.constant

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant

It would look something like:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.constant('OBJECT_A_ICON', 'fa-icona');
```

Or you could put them all in one object.

Answer (score 2):

Use a service:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('icons', function(){
    return {
        icon_1: '',
        icon_2: ''
    };
})

.controller('myController', function(icons) {
    console.log(icons.icon_1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for constants or immutable objects. There are no immutable objects in regular javascript or angular so you would probably want to use a standard $scope variable. MK's answer is pretty solid. This is kind of interesting: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/